# Subsequent visits to US for 10 Years US Visa Holders

Tags: visas, usa, esta

I have 10 years US visa and I am a Turkish citizen. I travel US on this visa once and I am planning another trip on January, 2016.

Do I need to do anything before this trip (e.g. like [ESTA](https://esta.cbp.dhs.gov/esta/))?

Comment: Make sure you have return tickets and enough money for your journey.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you do not need to do anything, other than to ensure you can convince the border official that you meet the conditions for admission associated with your visa type.

In particular, you should not apply for ESTA.  That system is for travellers seeking to enter under the visa waiver program (VWP).  You are seeking to enter with a visa, so you are not using the VWP, so you do not need ESTA.